# What are the buildings in Miniland in the Legoland Park set 40346-1?

Tags: model-identification

The [Legoland Park set 40346-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=40346-1) contains three plates with buildings/structures from the Legoland Miniland: https://www.mecabricks.com/en/models/8xaDX5zwaB7 (building instructions: https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/6282853.pdf )

[image: Legoland Miniland plates]

I can recognize some of them: Statue of Liberty, Golden Gate Bridge, Big Ben, Brandenburger Tor, perhaps [Nyhavn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyhavn).

But what are the rest supposed to be?

Answer (score 6):

The comment by user "Stephan3321" (the creator of the digital model) on the [linked page](https://www.mecabricks.com/en/models/8xaDX5zwaB7) lists the following buildings / monuments:

- Statue of Liberty
- Tower of London
- Steamboat Willie
- Golden Gate Bridge
- Brandenburg Gate
- Neuschwanstein Castle
- Burj Khalifa
- Petronas Twin Towers

The blue, lime, orange and brown buildings could be Nyhavn, indeed, but I couldn't find any official description.

Comment: There's also a mountain, perhaps Mount Fuji? Right beside what seems to be a cherry tree. Both are related to Japan.

Comment: @Alex That is plausible, but in the absence of an official description I'm pondering whether opening up this answer as a community wiki would be a better way of collecting ideas.

Comment: Yes, I did see that comment. I don't believe the Tower of London is there (perhaps he confuses it with Big Ben?) and I don't believe the boat is Steamboat Willie (wrong shape).

Comment: I think that the boat is steamboat willie. There isn’t to much that you can do with two studs.

Comment: Agree that it's likely to be Nyhavn - it's a fairly large section of the Billund LEGOLAND display. I think it's also got Billund Airport in it (the curved roof gives it away).